# How ask for administrator password before mounting any disk or image?

Tags: macos, password, permission, mount, root

I have a place with some mac computers and I don't want anybody mounting anything. Is there a way to ask for administrator's password before mount an USB or image?

Comment: Some old but possibly still relevant answers here: https://superuser.com/questions/531673/disable-auto-mounting-of-all-unknown-drives-on-os-x

Comment: "I have a place with some mac computers" What does this mean? Do you have an internet cafe? Do you maintain Macs in a public location you manage?

Comment: It's an office @IconDaemon

Comment: @calum_b I know about that program but it does not work for me.

Comment: You need to add information like this to your original question to save people duplicating effort & save this from becoming a 20-questions triage.